# User keywords return no value if they contain continuable failures in Robot Framework 2.8.5

Tags: python-2.7, exception, robotframework

The return value in the following code always comes as None instead of Hello There. I understand that this issue is because my keyword fails, but apart from going for a work-around way isn't there any other way this can be done? Note: I need the execution to continue upon failure but also be marked as FAIL.
The exact same issue was taken up here https://code.google.com/p/robotframework/issues/detail?id=1266
and apparently solved here https://code.google.com/p/robotframework/source/detail?r=e245a6135f8e#, but I don't think the solution stands true for RF 2.8.5 at least. Please help.

Thanks in advance :)

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test case 1
    ${x}=    My keyword
    Log    ${x}

*** Keywords ***
My keyword
    Run Keyword And Continue On Failure    Fail
    ${output}=    Set Variable    Hello there
    [Return]    ${output}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your keyword *is* returning a value. However, robot will halt a test case if a keyword fails so your log message is never executed.

If you want the log message to be printed, you must force robot to continue after the keyword fails. This is no different than how you handled the failure within the keyword:

```
Test case 1
    ${x}=  Run keyword and continue on failure   My Keyword
    Log    ${x}
```

**Note**: [Run keyword and continue on failure](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Continue%20On%20Failure) only affects the keyword or testcase it is in. In your case, it affects the running of your keyword but it does *not* affect anything that calls your keyword. Since you want your keyword to fail (and it does...), the test case that calls it will also fail and stop executing.

Comment: Dude Bryan.. if you notice, I Am using the Run Keyword And Continue on Failure keyword already! I hope you understood my question. Thanks a lot for your help anyway :)

Comment: You are using it in the keyword, but you _also_ need to use it in the test case. When you use it in the keyword, it only applies to the keyword. The test case is still in the "stop executing on failure" mode. When the keyword fails, it returns the result, but the test will stop executing before the log statement.